# Xamarin Webview auto login to website

Tags: c#, android, ios, webview, xamarin.forms

I am going to build Xamarin Forms app.

The authentication is proceeded in mobile app, and it gets authenticate token from login api.
The next page is webview and it loads website in which it skips login process as it is already logged in via mobile app.

Could you let me know how can implement that logic?

Thanks

Comment: If you are not bound to Xamarin you could take a look at React Native. I am personally more familiar with C# but I find React native more friendly, and easier to share code between Web and Mobile and easier to design if you are familiar with CSS. Also it lets you deal with requests in more natural way I assume you have API that returns some kind of JSON, so to me it's more natural to use some kind of scripting language so you can directly operate on the data without any deserialization like in case of C# you will probably need something like Json.NET. IMO it's nice to learn it.

Comment: Also each app I saw using Xamarin looks almost the same, near identical way and you will have problems adding things like video in the background and so on that you can do like in ~2 minutes using React. Reactive programming may seem weird at first and it's even more weird when using things like Redux. But there are alternatives if you don't like this architecture you can use Microsoftish ReSub(if i'm not wrong used on Skype for mobile devices - yup Skype is using React native). But let's say one day you will want to move your app from mobile to web-your C# code will be completely useless

Comment: I don't like JavaScript that much though but for me it's significantly harder to style in XAML than in CSS/CSS-like way. To sum it up: both ways suck. If you were game developer then Lua might be familiar to you. There's one interesting project that allows u to write mobile apps in Lua, but seems to be popular in Asia only :) https://github.com/alibaba/LuaViewSDK

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right and you want the user to be already logged in on the web view, there won't be a way around supplying some sort of token to the web server in order to authenticate your user. If it's a secure channel, why don't you just submit the token as a parameter for the web page you are requesting?